# Should I use "an" in case that the adjective starts with a vowel?

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-sided): The book presents **a** one-sided view of history.

I'm confused. I thought that it should be **an** one-sided view of history. Could you please explain this case to me?

I know that the article is for the noun (view) not for the adjective (one-sided) but I was told that even if a word starts with a consent which sounds like a vowel, it should be preceded with "an" not "a". So I always thought the grammar rule is based on a vocal need. What I mean by this is that it is easier for Native English speakers to say "an" one-sided instead of "a" one-sided.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the initial letter, but on the initial sound.

Comment: @Davo So it is "an online application" because "online" starts with "o" sound and it is "a one-sided view" because one starts with "wa" sound ?

Comment: @Costa - You got it. I would be **a** one-sided view, but **an** eight-sided view.